# CSS , GWT and reading composed class name

Tags: css, gwt

in a GWT project I have a CSS with

```
.my_datagrid tr {
    height: 26px; 
}
```

and in my client code i do

grid.getElement().setClassName("my_datagrid");

that modify the minimum hight (i know isn't final) of datagrid rows, i would need for some reason to set this property (the TR height value) code way or at least read it...but the tr part make it over my understanding,

i tried with 
     grid.getElement().getPropertyString("tr height")
or
with 
    dataGrid.getElement().getStyle().getProperty("tr height")

but doesn't work..I understand that i'm working on the data grid element and not on the row but i need to know (or set) the minimal height BEFORE any row is added.

So..anyone knows how to read from css that value or remove it from css and set directly code way on my data grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to tweak the CSS itself, then you have to use the CSSOM to manipulate the stylesheet (independently of where it's applied through matching).

GWT doesn't provide a CSSOM API, so you'll have to use JSNI. Also, beware of cross-browser support.

With a `DataGrid` widget, you'd better use a custom `CellTableBuilder` where you can inject inline `style=""` attributes on each generated row and/or cell.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but i think I don't understand it: why i should tweak the css? I would like to set from javascript (java js compiled since i'm working client side) the style value or read it..the huge problem is that I still don't have the element because not created.

Comment: "set the style value [without an] element because not created" == modifying the **rule** that will apply to the elements that will be created == "tweak the CSS".

Answer (score 0):

To set a row height on all rows, you do:

```
myDataGrid.addStyleName("my_datagrid");
```

There is no way to set a height of all rows to a specific number other than by using a CSS class, but you can set height of a single row:

```
myDataGrid.getRowElement(index).getStyle().setHeight(26, Unit.PX);
```

If you need a height of a row, you can do:

```
int h = myDataGrid.getRowElement(index).getOffsetHeight();
```

Note that the actual height of a row may be different from the "style" setting, because text can wrap to have more than one line (unless you prevent it).

Comment: Nop. this is what I already do, please notice that in my request I'm asking to set the value of height code way, not the style, i want to remove the style setting

Comment: but isn't what i would need ;) it's the code way to set the style to the grid, i'm asking how to set code way the height value....just to be more precise: i have an integer and i want to set runtime the height OR i want an integer that say me runtime the value of height